# Google Web Components don't render when used with iron-pages

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, dart-polymer

I am having an issue where I cannot get google-maps to load within iron-pages. I have found a [Git Issue](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-pages/issues/13) logged but there is no reply.

Anyone know a temporary fix for this issue?

Thanks Matt

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the issue was being cause by the map element having a height of 0px. I rectified this issue by ensuring the top level element was an iron-flex-layout and propagating the following css attributes to all elements/div down to the level of the map element.

```
    @apply(--layout-flex);
    @apply(--layout-vertical);
```

Matt